# AdAway alternative for non-rooted Android devices?

Tags: android, ad-blocker

Can anyone recommend an alternative to AdAway for non-rooted Android devices?

The desired functionality is to block advertisements ***within all apps***, not just within a web browser.

Any price is fine, as long as it does not involve a recurring fee.

Interested in answers for all versions of Android.

Comment: Does lucky patcher work with non-rooted devices? Don't know, its just a suggesion.

Comment: @GBolt Even if it would (which I doubt), it would not be a good match: one had to patch all affected apps manually, and remember re-patching them after updates. Plus it's too tempting using some of its other functionality (those where one gets into the "dark grey area") – a temptation one better avoids :)

Comment: Try [VPN HOSTS(NO ROOT)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.xfalcon.vhosts&hl=en). Download and extract hosts file from [MoaAB](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1916098) open VPN hosts and select extracted hosts file

Answer (score 1):

You can find some candidates in my app-list of [Ad-Blocker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_adblocker)s. But without root, air is thin. My recommendation here would be **[Block This!](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/com.savageorgiev.blockthis).** Not using it myself, but I got positive feedback from friends using it. The link just given leads to my F-Droid repository, where you can get the app (and, when using the repo with the F-Droid client, also be notified for updates). It's unfortunately not available in the official repository (yet?), or at Google Play. But you can find additional details on [the project's Github presence](https://github.com/ggsava/block-this).

So let's see how it matches your needs:

- **for non-rooted Android devices:** Yes.
- **block advertisements within all apps, not just within a web browser:** Yes. It's a DNS based AdBlocker, using Android's VPN functionality to work globally.
- **Any price is fine, as long as it does not involve a recurring fee.** No such subscription. No idea where to direct payment to: this one is FOSS (GPL licensed).

Comment: I've been reading up on it, and it doesn't look like it can also block *everything* for certain apps (this working as a firewall).  Please correct me if I'm mistaken.  Because it runs as a VPN, it won't work with no-root firewalls, and since it can't block everything for certain apps, it won't replace a firewall.

Comment: I didn't say it replaces a firewall. You asked for an ad blocker, not for a firewall. According to reports I've got, AddThis! works fine as ad blocker. Have you tried it, or just read about it?

Comment: I know, you didn't say that. ;)  I'm saying it isn't compatible with any no-root firewalls that I have found, and that if I have to pick between a firewall and an ad blocker, I'll probably pick a firewall.

Comment: Understood. But you neither said it must be compatible with a non-root firewall. Unfortunately, that's not possible, as without root the only way of blocking such things is using a VPN; so either you find an app covering both aspects (ad blocker and firewall), or you have to decide between the two.

Comment: Yes... seems to be true.  (Unless someone knows something about this that we don't know!)  I found 2 firewalls that can do some ad blocking... still researching...

Comment: @RockPaperLizard According to the [Netguard FAQ](https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard/blob/master/FAQ.md) (see #2), *NetGuard* supports SOCKS5 proxy to chain VPN applications. That way you could use BlockThis! as AdBlocker via VPN, and NetGuard via SOCKS5 chain as firewall. Not tried, just saw the note.

Comment: Thanks. I'm taking a look at it now.